# How to add items from a text file into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've already tried:

```
with open('names.txt', 'r') as f:
    myNames = f.readlines()
```

And multiple other ways that I have found on stack overflow but they are not doing exactly what I need.

I have a text file that has one line with multiple words ex: 
FLY JUMP RUN

I need these in a list but for them to be separate elements in the list like:

```
['FLY', 'JUMP', 'RUN']
```

Except when using the the methods I find on stack overflow, I get: 
`['FLY JUMP RUN']`

But I need them to be separate because I am using the random.choice method on the list.

Comment: `myNames = f.read().split()`

Comment: @user3100115: you should post that as an answer

Comment: Thanks! So basically readlines() will put a whole line into a list and read() will separate the items in a line? I'm guessing it will work for integers as well?

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments, you should try

```
myNames = None
with open('names.txt', 'r') as f:
    myNames = f.read().split()
```

Assuming the file is written the way you say.  Of course it won't matter as the default behaviour of split() is to split the string, using whitespace characters like spaces, and newline characters, so if your file consists of

```
One Two
Three
```

then

```
f.read().split()
```

will still return

```
["One", "Two", "Three"]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Trey: To answer your comment.

No. `readlines()` will read all the contents of the file into a single list while `read()` simply reads it as a single strring.

Try this code:

```
with open('names.txt', 'r') as f:
    myNames = f.read().split() #split by space
```

This will work as you expected for any type of data, as long as the words in a line is space separated.

Comment: `f.read()` does not read one line at a time. It reads the whole contents of the file into one string.